# Spring Boot applications, using a value/state between 2 services

Tags: java, spring-boot, singleton, microservices

I have 2 *Spring Boot* applications let's say named ***Application1*** and ***Application2***. I have a *state/mode/status* whatever you call it in ***Application2***, whose value should be ON when **Application1** runs a scheduler and will be OFF when it's stopped.
This status value should be singleton in ***Application2***.

How can ***Application1*** change the status value(Singleton) in ***Application2***.

Please help me How can I implement it in *Spring Boot*?

Comment: your question indicates that you're missing foundational pieces that are outside the scope of a stack overflow answer. I would suggest reading about rest services and going through a couple spring-boot tutorials on how to implement a rest service.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a rest service say `getStatus()` in *Applicaton1* which will be providing the status of the scheduler (ON or OFF Status). `getStatus()` can be called from *Application2* using *RestTemplate*.

Comment: I edited the question little bit, please check. To your answer, I don't want to call an API. It increases the response time unnecessarily.